# How to fix pixilated fire in render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, smoke-simulation, fire

Shows fine in the 3d view but renders blocky / pixilated. How can I fix this?

[image: 3D View]
[image: Render]

Comment: normally this kind of problem can be solved by turning up the resolution. Which value did you enter for domain resolution?

Comment: @Chris It's not the resolution (as the 3D view shows). The problem is adding the _Emission_ shader to the _Principled Volume_. I'll make an answer of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your material setup is that you're adding the *Emission* shader to the *Principled Volume*. But the *Emission* gets its value from a *Color Ramp* set to a factor of 0.5 - since there is nothing plugged in, it's 0.5 overall.

And this means it adds 0.5 to all voxels (actually no, but the color at 0.5 in the ramp multiplied by the *Emission Strength* of 1), no matter what density there is since you have no density or flame value as input for the *Emission*. And so every voxel has an overall density of bigger than 0 which makes their cubic shape visible.

The following example shows how you could setup a fire material. The emission and the flame color needs a factor to be multiplied with so that the densitiy of smoke and fire will be taken into account. This is by no means a perfect, realistic looking fire, it's just a simple setup to get rid of the voxel cubes. I would suggest you watch some tutorials on how to create fire (make sure they are for Mantaflow and not the old system), a decent looking fireball and a good tutorial is this one from Polyfjord for example, [Tutorial: Creating a Fireball in Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zyIJQHlFQs0)

[image: fire material]

Below is just a quick sketch to illustrate what happens in your material compared to my material. From left to right:

- The voxel size is determined by your domain's *Resolution Divisions* setting, of course a higher value gives smaller voxels and less noticeable blockiness.
- After simulating smoke and fire, these voxels contain density information consisting of values from 0 to 1.
- Your *Color Ramp* produces a color according to the factor plugged in, you just have a constant value of 0.5 which makes it overall medium orange, and since there is no density information, the *Emission* shader fills the voxel completely.
- What your material now does is adding this overall emission to the density, which means even the parts which have a density of zero now get a constant value above 0 - which makes the borders of the voxel clearly visible.
- When using the density (or flame information if you simulated smoke+fire) as a factor for the *Emission Strength* and the *Color Ramp*, the emission will be relative to the density/flame and not add something to empty space. Note that also the emission color now varies according to the density information instead of having one constant color.

[image: fire comparison]